# Pass Complicated JSON between Flow and LWC, or from LWC Screen Component in Flow to another LWC Screen Component (in another step)

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, collection-variable

Hello all clever SFDC Developers,
I wonder is there any way I can pass a collection of Apex-defined from Flow to Screen,
working with property type and property in the typeconfig of corresponding LWC js meta xml file doesn't work..

```
            <propertyType name="ProductUnit" extends="apex://myNameSpace.ProductUnitVO" label="Product Unit"/>
            <property name="configuringUnits" type="{ProductUnit[]}" label="Configuring Units Units" description="The List of Product Units"/>
```

I'm trying to pass complicated object from one LWC to another LWC (each is on different step of the flow). I've tried LMS channel, however that was the result came from lack of understand about Flow. Each Screen Component doesn't exist on same page and actually the custom aura container (I thought) is refreshed when next flow event is invoked, so every try of subscribing the published event was unable.

Can you give me any guidence of achieving this? Would very appreciate!

Comment: Are you aware that you can pass arrays of your own [Apex aura enabled classes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_flow_data_types)?

Comment: @PhilW Yes :)
Can you teach me how to pass the arrays of my own Apex aura enabled class from flow to LWC?
I succeeded passing an object of Apex class type, however Array of Apex class type -> having difficulty of achieving that now.

Comment: Assuming ProductUnit is your aura enabled apex class, have you tried setting the property type to `List<ProductUnit>`? You seem to be trying to define the type as a JavaScript object containing an unnamed product unit array, which isn't appropriate.